# Collecting text box values in Visual Basic

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have some Javascript code that assigns a value to a text box:

```
document.getElementById('longitudeTextBox').value = location.coords.longitude;
```

What I want to do is get the value of that text box over to Visual Basic:

```
Dim Logitude As String = longitudeTextBox.Text
```

This works if the code is inside a button, but if I use it on a page event like `Page_Load`, I'm not receiving any data.

Comment: You won't get any data on `Page_Load`, no one has time to enter data before this event fires. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: the javascript enters the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it when pageload.complete = true

Comment: How do you determine when pageload.complese = true?

Comment: Well, you make an if-clause and put it in a timer that checks for true every x seconds.  The property is described in detail here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx